# The missing quines: Visual Basic (for Applications)

Tags: vba, quine

Today I surfed some random geek-stuff articles on wikipedia to get my daily dose of useless knowledge. I stumbled accross quines, which are programs that print their own source-code. I found that a great way to make my brain hurt, so I began working on a quine in VBA. I had two good reasons:

1. I couldn't find a quine written in VBA
2. VBA encourages you to write awkward code which makes your brain hurt

Here is my masterpiece:

```
Sub q()
c = "Sub q();c = #;Debug.Print Replace(Replace(c, Chr(59), vbNewLine), Chr(35), Chr(34) & c & Chr(34));End Sub"
Debug.Print Replace(Replace(c, Chr(59), vbNewLine), Chr(35), Chr(34) & c & Chr(34))
End Sub
```

**My challenge: Can you make it even shorter (and preferably more awkward)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if anybody reads this thread anomore but here's an even shorter one, based on the quine of das_weezul. It's independent of "Option Explicit" (unlike das_weezul's) and it's independent of the Office App you are working in (i.e. Excel, Access, Word etc.) - unlike Alex K's. Use it in the immediate window (Ctrl+G):

```
c="c=#:?replace(c,chr(35),chr(34) &c &chr(34))":?replace(c,chr(35),chr(34) &c &chr(34))
```

Comment: You can even make that one four characters shorter: `c="c=#:a=chr(34):?replace(c,chr(35),a &c &a)":a=chr(34):?replace(c,chr(35),a &c &a)`

Comment: I'm still reading this :D It's great to see this thread coming back to life. That solution looks really slick!

Comment: Sorry @Alex K, Dorian seized the throne :D

Comment: @Dorian I've added a couple of tricks to this answer, and you can see it below - let me know if you find anything else that makes it shorter

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
Sub q() '//in mdl1
Debug.Print Workbooks(1).VBProject.VBComponents(5).CodeModule.Lines(1, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: I knew someone would come up with that ;) +2 for length, -1 for good readability ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some further modifications of [@Dorian I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5078105/dorian-i)'s response gets the bytecount for the VBA quine to come down to 77 bytes

```vb
c=Chr(34):q="c=Chr(34):q=:?Replace(q,Chr(7),c+q+c)":?Replace(q,Chr(7),c+q+c)
```

The key tricks that allow for this to happen are the use of character 7, , over character 35, `#`, and using string addition rather than string concatenation.

Comment: Very good. I didn't even know that it's possible to add strings in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "printing itself", this could work (32 bytes):

```vb
Sub q()
SendKeys "^p~q~"
End Sub
```

It sends the keys :

1. `CTRL+p` : To print the current active code module (named Quine in my case).
2. `ENTER` (~) : To press OK in the dialog box.

[image]

3. `q+ENTER` : To submit the name of the file.

It will use your default printer which is `Microsoft Print to PDF` in my case, so I get this:

[image]

Big thanks to [Chris Rae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498949/chris-rae) for the inspiration found here: https://chrisrae.com/vba/routines/printmyself.html

Comment: Very creative solution, I didn't think of other interpretations of "printing" <3